# Reshape package from long to wide

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a long data set that I'd like to make wide, and I'm wondering if there is a way to do this all in one step using R's reshape packages.

The data frame df looks like this:

```
     Date      Time   value
   <chr>     <time> <dbl>
 1 Wednesday 16:09  10.7 
 2 Wednesday 16:10   8.86
 3 Wednesday 16:11   8.59
 4 Wednesday 16:12   8.59
 5 Wednesday 16:13   7.51
 6 Wednesday 16:14   6.71
 7 Wednesday 16:15   6.44
 8 Wednesday 16:16   4.83
 9 Wednesday 16:17   4.56
10 Wednesday 16:18   4.29
```

I'd like to get to this:

```
Date           16:09 16:10  16:11   16:12 ...
Wednesday      10.7   8.86    8.59   8.59     

   
   Sample code: 

df_wide<-reshape(df, idvar = "Time", v.names="value", timevar = "Date" , direction = "wide")  

                 

Sample data:

    structure(list(Date = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"), Time = structure(c(58140, 
58200, 58260, 58320, 58380, 58440, 58500, 58560, 58620, 58680, 
58740, 58800, 58860, 58920, 58980, 59040, 59100, 59160, 59220, 
59280, 59340, 59400, 59460, 59520, 59580, 59640, 59700, 59760, 
59820, 59880, 59940, 60000), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    value = c(10.733333, 8.855, 8.586667, 8.586667, 7.513333, 
    6.708333, 6.44, 4.83, 4.561667, 4.293333, 3.756667, 3.756667, 
    3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 3.756667, 4.025, 3.756667, 
    4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 5.635, 5.366667, 5.903333, 4.83, 
    4.83, 5.098333, 4.83, 7.781667, 7.245, 6.171667)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Time = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_time", 
    "collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: I took a look at `reshape` and honestly I couldn't figure out how this one works. So I posted an (imho) easier alternative instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Date ~ Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tidyr` instead:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Time, values_from=value)
```